# Javascript ES6 array loop that populates code only when on certain pages

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, innerhtml

i'm in school currently learning how to program using javascript (forgive me if my terminology is bad. feel free to correct me.) Myself and a team of four are creating a site. the requirements are that we must have 4 pages and each page needs to have a loop of some kind, we must use bootstrap, and we can only use one js file for all the pages. We are using a printToDom function to populate bootstrap cards on separate pages, and for some reason i can't get mine to work. i'm wondering if this has something to do with how our code is set up, specifically the for loops we're using. is there a way that i can incorporate an if statement that makes it to where our printToDom will print certain pieces of the for loop when on different pages? If so is there a term for it or something i can look up to get more insight?

EDIT: I probably should have said this in my original post, but I'm considering merging the two for loops that are seen in my code below because currently i have 2 separate for loops, but only one gets populated when on the tours page, the other one is supposed to populate some recent events from the array `recentEvents` but it doesn't. I tested it in JS fiddle and the code works there so i'm just wondering why it won't work when in the js file along side the rest of the code and I'm not sure how to phrase what i'm looking for.

javascript below for more context

```
    const tourStops=[
    {           location: "Denver, Colorado ",
                venue: " Pepsi Center ",
                date: "MON 04/20/2020",
                id: 1
    },
    {
                location: "Las Vegas, Nevada",
                venue: " Flamingo Hotel",
                date: "FRI 04/24/2020",
                id: 2
    },
    {
                location: "Hollywood, California",
                venue: " Troubadour ",
                date: "SAT  05/02/2020",
                id: 3
    },
    {
                location: "Portland,Oregon",
                venue: " Moda Center ",
                date: "FRI  05/15/2020",
                id: 4
    },
    {
                location: "Washington, D.C. ",
                venue: " Capital One Arena",
                date: "FRI  05/22/2020",
                id: 5
    },
    {
                location: "Bangor, Maine ",
                venue: " Darlings Waterfront",
                date: "FRI  06/05/2020",
                id: 6
    },
    {
                location: "Boston, Massachusetts",
                venue: " Wilbur Theater ",
                date: "SAT  06/20/2020",
                id: 7
    },
    {
                location: "Anchorage, Alaska ",
                venue: "Atwood Concert Hall",
                date: "THU  07/09/2020",
                id: 8
    }
    ];



    const printToDom =(divId,textToPrint)=>{
    const selectedDiv= document.getElementById(divId);
    selectedDiv.innerHTML= textToPrint;
    };


    const buildTourDates=()=>{
        let domString='';
        for(let i = 0; i <tourStops.length;i++){
            domString += '<div class="container px-lg-5">';
            domString += '<div class="row mx-lg-n5">';
            domString += `<div class="col py-3 px-lg-5 border">${tourStops[i].date}</div>`;
            domString += `<div class="col py-3 px-lg-5 border">${tourStops[i].location}</div>`;
            domString += `<div class="col py-3 px-lg-5 border">${tourStops[i].venue}</div>`;
            domString += `<a class="btn btn-success border" href="https://www.ticketnetwork.com/en/concerts" role="button" id= "tickets" onclick= "btnPurchase(${tourStops[i].id})" class="btn btn-success border">Purchase Tickets</a>`;
            domString += '</div>';
            domString += '</div>';
    }
    printToDom('tourdates',domString)
    };


    const btnPurchase= (id)=>{
     for(let i=0; i < tourStops.length; i++){  
         if(tourStops[i].id === id) {
    return;
}
  }
    };

    const eventsForTickets = () => {
        document.getElementById("tickets").addEventListener('click', btnPurchase);
    };


    const recentEvents = [
        {
            event: "New Tour!",
            para: "text to be inserted into this event. Lorum ipsum to see how more text looks.",
            img: ""
        },
        {
            event: "New Album",
            para: "text to be inserted into this event. Lorum ipsum to see how more text looks.",
            img: ""
        },
        {
            event: "Something",
            para: "text to be inserted into this event. Lorum ipsum to see how more text looks.",
            img: ""
        },

    ];



    const buildEvents = () => {
        let domString='';
        for(let i = 0; i < recentEvents.length; i++){
            domString += `<div class="media">`;
            domString += `<img src="..." class="mr-3" alt="...">`;
            domString += `<div class="media-body">`;
            domString += ` <h5 class="mt-0">${recentEvents[i].event}</h5>`;
            domString += `${recentEvents[i].para}`;
            domString += `</div>`;
            domString += `</div>`;
        }
    printToDom('newEvents',domString)
    };


    const initTour=()=> {
     buildTourDates(tourStops);
     eventsForTickets();
    };

    const initIndex=()=>{
        buildEvents(recentEvents);
    }

    initTour();
    initIndex();
```

Comment: Can you creste a working example of what you have tried in https://jsfiddle.net or here in codepen.io .. Put your respective html, css and JS in respective places..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method `window.location.pathname` that get the name of the specific page in which you are, according to it then you can do something like that

```
const pageRoute = window.location.pathname

if(pageRoute == "page-one"){
    buildTourDates()
} else if(pageRoute == "page-two"){
    buildEvents()
}//so on...
```

Comment: so where you have "page-one" would i put the file path instead?

Comment: I'll give it a shot!